# C# New bitmap() - Out of memory

Tags: c#, bitmap, out-of-memory, emgucv, dispose

I'm newbie at DotNet programming. I got a serious problem for me but I don't know why. I already used `Dispose()` method but "Out of memory" problem still occurs. At about first 30 times, everything works perfectly. Then, `Out of memory` happens. Furthermore, the images is from 13-16Mb. This is my code:

```
private void advanBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InvertFunction();
}

private void InverFunction()
{
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(imgBox.Image); // Out of memory
    Image<Gray, byte> EmguImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(bm);
    EmguImage = EmguImage.Not();
    imgBox.Image.Dispose();
    imgBox.Image = EmguImage.Bitmap;
    bm.Dispose();
    EmguImage.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: how big is the image?

Comment: You miss to dispose one Image<Gray,byte> instance.

Comment: Excatly ! creating EMGU directly (without first creating a bitmap) and using block will free up memory properly IMHO

Comment: @VDN the image is from 13 - 16Mb.

Comment: @SirRufo What is the image I miss to dispose? Coz I did it at two lines `bm.Dispose()` and `EmguImage.Dispose()`

Comment: i see you have now disposed both images, is it working fine ?

Comment: @ankit_sharma No, I just added the size of images in my post. I have used `Dispose()` method for both images at the first time but It is not working fine.

Comment: @TinChip You dispose **two** images from **three** images you create. *EmguImage.Not()* creates a new image instance too!

Comment: @SirRufo Is it really a new image instance?. I have thought I create `EmguImage` and applied `Not()` method to the same images. If you are right, I want to ask "How to dispose `EmguImage.Not()?"

Comment: @TinChip It is an open source library and you can have a look at the source of that method - Dispose it as you dispose any other disposable instance. There is no difference.

Comment: After creating a new variable like `NewEmgu = EmguImage.Not()` and `Dispose()` both `NewEmgu` and `EmguImage`, it worked well. Thank you so much @SirRufo

Answer (score 3):

Try the suggestion in their [documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#Automatic_Garbage_Collection).

> The time of when garbage collector decides to dispose the image is not
>   guaranteed. When working with large image, it is recommend to call the
>   Dispose() method to explicitly release the object. Alternatively, use
>   the using keyword in C# to limit the scope of the image

```
    using (Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(imgBox.Image))
    {
        using (Image<Gray, Single> image = new Image<Gray, Single>(bm))
        {
            EmguImage = EmguImage.Not();
            imgBox.Image.Dispose();
            imgBox.Image = EmguImage.Bitmap;
        }
    }
```

As a last resort you can try forcing garbage collection. BUT this is not recomended and should be used only if you have no other way.

```
  GC.Collect();
```

I would suggest you to read about it before using it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: why create bitmap first ? rather than creating Emgu image directly using imgBox.Image.Bitmap ?

Comment: I cannot use `using` coz you can see that I try to assign a new value to to `using` variable at line `EmguImage = EmguImage.Not();`.Is there another way to deal with this situation?

Comment: I read the documentation already. Since images is from 13-16Mb, I called `Dispose()` method instead of using `using` keyword. Another reason is because I assign new value to image, I can not use `using` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be applicable anymore, but there were some version of the CLR that definitely had bugs with the LOH, where images normally get allocated. Might want to check that topic. A workaround was to manually check, if there was enough coherent memory (for external memory allocation) before allocating, which is a bit of a pain to do in C#. Just suggesting that you might not do something wrong.

I also had the problems with using OpenCV/Emgu and used opencvsharp for some problems. It is a more direct wrapper where you have to be very careful about memory allocation. It has been some time though and I cannot really remember the exaxt problem. It had to do with memory allocation. It should also be fixed by now I think.

Ended up having both as a dependency and it doesn't help for having clean code.

Otherwise, try to use the using statement other answers are suggesting. It calls .Dispose() automatically and starting the GC right away. That way, your memory doesn't fragment as much. You can also write..

```
using(Image a, Image b, Image c, ...) {}
```

... as long as the object implement IDisposable

Comment: Thanks for your advise. However, I cannot use using coz you can see that I try to assign a new value to to using variable at line EmguImage = EmguImage.Not();.Is there another way to deal with this situation?